# Редактирование текста как в google docs

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Как можно сделать ввод текста с возможностью форматирования (жирный/курсив/цветной итд...) как это реализовано в google docs.

Чтоб пользователю не приходилось расставлять теги html

P.S. Так-как обычный input такое не поддерживает, у меня в голове только решение - обрабатывать ввод c помощью js, и внедрять в html.  Если это единственное решение, как тогда сделать курсор, чтоб он еще попадал в нужное место при клике.. А выделение надеюсь как-то осилю.

Comment: Гуглится как Javascript WYSIWYG

Comment: libreoffice online, если сможете собрать из git. Здесь можно найти виртуальную машину с офисом онлайн https://www.collaboraoffice.com/code/ чтобы заценить. https://owncloud.org/blog/libreoffice-online-has-arrived-in-owncloud/

Comment: Попроще http://ckeditor.com/, https://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: здесь весьма неплохой обзор редакторов на все случаи:) http://www.coolwebmasters.com/codes-and-scripts/691-10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Чтоб написать самому:**
Вот то что нужно:
https://learn.javascript.ru/range-textrange-selection

Там есть все, в том числе и определить куда в тексте кликнул пользователь, чтоб поставить туда курсор ввода. Там конечно моей задачи не рассматривается.. но я другого решения, извините не вижу

**Чтоб НЕ написать самому:**
А так Vladimir Gamalian (оставил комментарий в теме) прав: "Гуглится как Javascript WYSIWYG" - это если нужно готовое решение!
Вот список готовых работ под самыми разными лицензиями
https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable/wiki/Javascript-WYSIWYG-editors
Вообще полно инфы в интернете, оказывается, и под лицензией Mit тоже есть